# List values lost in Python Multiprocessing

Tags: python-3.x, parallel-processing, networkx, python-multiprocessing

I would like to parallelise a series of tasks operating on a list of `NetworkX` graphs. For parallelisation I use the `Manager` and `Process` objects from the `Multiprocessing` module. In the minimal example below there is only one process calculating the adjacency matrix of each `NetworkX` graph. The set of graphs is stored in a list `Gt`. Each particular graph from this set is called `Gk`. Similarly, the adjacency matrices are stored in a list called `At`, while each particular matrix corresponding to a graph `Gk` is called `Ak`. I use keyword arguments to pass the global list of adjacency matrices `At` and an index `k` to a function `adj_mtrx()`. My problem is that I cannot obtain the calculated adjacency values in the main body of the program. `At[k]` are all zeroes. If possible, would you please take a look at the minimal example below and direct me to my mistake?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import networkx   as nx
import numpy      as np
import random     as rnd

from multiprocessing import Manager, Process

# Generates random graph
def gen_rnd_graph(nv, ne):
    
    # Create random list of sources
    Vsrc = [rnd.randint(0,nv-1) for iter in range(ne)]
    
    # Create random list of sinks
    Vsnk = [rnd.randint(0,nv-1) for iter in range(ne)]
    
    # Create random list of edge weights
    U = [rnd.random() for iter in range(ne)]
    
    # Create list of tuples {Vsrc, Vsnk, U}
    T = list(zip(Vsrc,Vsnk,U))
    
    # Create graph
    G = nx.Graph()
    
    # Create list of vertices
    V = list(range(nv))
    
    # Add nodes to graph
    G.add_nodes_from(V)
    
    # Add edges between random vertices with random edge weights
    G.add_weighted_edges_from(T)
    
    return G

# Generates random time-varying graph
def gen_time_graph(nv, ne, ng):

    # Initialise list of graphs
    l = []

    for i in range(ng):
        gi = gen_rnd_graph(nv, ne)
        l.append(gi)

    return l

# Computes adjacency matrix for snaphot of time-varying graph
def adj_mtrx(Gk, **kwargs):

    At = kwargs.get("At", None)
    k  = kwargs.get("k",  None)

    print("in   adj_mtrx id(At):", id(At))

    # no. of vertices
    n = Gk.number_of_nodes()

    # adjacency matrix
    Ak = np.zeros([n,n])

    # for each vertex
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(n):
            if Gk.has_edge(i,j):
                Ak[i,j] = 1
                print("func Ak[{0:d},{1:d}]: {2:f}".format(i, j, Ak[i,j]))
    
                # Store new At[k] values
                if At != None and k != None:

                    At[k][i,j] = Ak[i,j]
                
                    if At[k][i,j] > 0.0:
                        print("func At[{0:d}][{1:d},{2:d}]: {3:f}".format(k, i, j, At[k][i,j]))

    return Ak

def main():

    with Manager() as manager:

        #-----------------------------------------------------------------------
        # Specify constants
        #-----------------------------------------------------------------------
        NV  = 10  # no. of vertices
        NE  = 15  # no. of edges
        NG  =  3  # no. of snapshot graphs

        #-----------------------------------------------------------------------
        # Generate random time-varying graph
        #-----------------------------------------------------------------------
        Gt = manager.list()
        Gt = gen_time_graph(NV, NE, NG)

        # Snapshot index
        k = 0
        
        # Initialise list of temporal adjacency matrics
        At     = manager.list()
        At     =[np.zeros([NV,NV])]*NG
        print("create id(At):", id(At))

        # for each snapshot graph
        for Gk in Gt:
            
            print("k: {0:d}".format(k))

            processes = []
    
            # Temporal adjacency matrix
            print("pre  adj_mtrx id(At):", id(At))
            p1 = Process( target=adj_mtrx, args=(Gk,), kwargs={"At": At, "k": k} )
            print("post adj_mtrx id(At):", id(At))
            p1.start()
            processes.append(p1)
            
            # Wait for process 1
            p1.join()

            # @test
            [m,n] = np.shape(At[k])
        
            for i in range(m):
                for j in range(n):
                    if At[k][i,j] > 0.0:
                        print("body At[{0:d}][{1:d},{2:d}]: {3:f}".format(k, i, j, At[k][i,j]))

            k += 1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1):

multiprocessing supports two types of communication channel between processes: multiprocessing.Queue and multiprocessing.Pipe.

In your function 'adj_mtrx' you are modifying 'At' variable, which in your case is a deep copy of the 'At' variable you are passing to Process(…) in the 'main' function. All modifications to the 'At' variable will be local to the 'adj_mtrx'.

Comment: Yes, intuitively I understand this. My task is to share the data between processes in the most efficient way. I thought a list managed by a common 'Manager' should be sufficient. But it isn't.

Comment: In general, sharing data among threads or processes is inefficient, because data access synchronization becomes the bottleneck. In your particular case, the Python API offers multiprocessing.Queue type, that you can use to gather results from child processes. Basically, you have to pass the same instance of multiprocessing.Queue to all child processes and, once processes finish, you combine results. Essentially, replace "At[k][i,j] = Ak[i,j]" line with "q.put([k, i, j, Ak[i,j]])". And in the "main" function, after process finishes, combine results from queue into the "At" list.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Multiprocessing.Pool class.
Instantiate a pool with the number of processes you want to run in parallel and use its map function to iterate over the list of graphs and calculate the adj matrix for each graph using your function.
In fact networkx provides it's own function for calculating adj matrix  (nx.to_numpy_array)

see the code below :

```
import networkx   as nx
import numpy      as np
import random     as rnd
import multiprocessing
from multiprocessing import Pool

# Generates random graph
def gen_rnd_graph(nv, ne):
    G = nx.gnm_random_graph(nv, ne, seed=None, directed=False)

    for s, t in G.edges():
        G[s][t]['weight'] = rnd.random()

    return G


# Generates random time-varying graph
def gen_time_graph(nv, ne, ng):
    # Initialise list of graphs
    l = []

    for i in range(ng):
        gi = gen_rnd_graph(nv, ne)
        l.append(gi)

    return l


# Computes adjacency matrix for snaphot of time-varying graph
def adj_mtrx(Gk):
    Ak = nx.to_numpy_array(Gk, weight=1)  # weight parameter make sure adj is 1 instead of actual weight
    return Ak


def main():
    num_of_processes = multiprocessing.cpu_count() // 2
    print('num_of_process={}'.format(num_of_processes))

    # -----------------------------------------------------------------------
    # Specify constants
    # -----------------------------------------------------------------------
    NV = 10  # no. of vertices
    NE = 15  # no. of edges
    NG = 3  # no. of snapshot graphs

    # -----------------------------------------------------------------------
    # Generate random time-varying graph
    # -----------------------------------------------------------------------

    Gt = gen_time_graph(NV, NE, NG)

    with Pool(num_of_processes) as p:
        At = p.map(adj_mtrx, Gt)

    for k in range(NG):
        print(Gt[k].edges())
        print(At[k])
        print('==========')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I've also used networkx random graph generation method to make the code more compact, it differs slightly from your implementation as it wont have self edges and it guarantees that NE edges will be produced (no duplicate edges)